# I wonder if the way Kafka works is what I understand

Tags: apache-kafka

I wonder if the structure I understood is correct.

On Kafka's side are producers, consumers, and the zookeeper ensemble.
It communicates on the topic, and the partition is a parallel processing unit, and only the replay leader can input and output.

When the producers ask a random Kafka about " what partition has and who is the leader, ".
And that kafka ask to zookeeper, And responds.
The producer who gets the answer sends a message to Kafka Broker.
The broker then receives it, saves it, and informs any zookeeper.(Increased Offset)
Here, the zookeeper sends the information receives to the zookeeper leader, who informs the other zookeeper.
If the leader dies, the leader is replaced in the " Zookeeper Arctic broadcast " way.

In addition, if the Kafka partition leader dies, the Kafka Controller recognizes it and manages the partition leader.
When the entire process is completed, it sends a message to consumers.

Is this correct?

I have a question.
If only one producer is too busy, only the partition that receives that information becomes very busy?
Does it have to be managed manually?

Comment: You might be interested in picking up Kafka Definitive Guide book

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been looking for it.